# Случайный результат из подзапроса

Tags: sql, postgresql

Смог составить два запроса.

Выборка которая мне нужна:

```
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM msgall WHERE bot_answer IS NOT NULL
```

И случайный выбор (подсмотрел тут рядом):

```
SELECT text FROM msgall LIMIT 1 OFFSET FLOOR(random() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msgall))
```

Как их правильно объединить - получить одну случайную ячейку из приведенного запроса?

Comment: `with x as( первый запрос ) select ... from X ....`

Comment: Благодарю за наводку!

`WITH tmp_arr as ( SELECT DISTINCT text FROM msgall WHERE bot_answer IS NOT NULL )
SELECT text FROM tmp_arr LIMIT 1 OFFSET FLOOR(random() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_arr))`